# Parse complete xml value

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

I have the following piece of xml:

```
<title><![CDATA[ ヴァン・ヘルシング (字幕版)]]></title>
```

To parse the value, I am doing:

```
title=node.xpath("//t:title")
title = title[0].text
u' \u30f4\u30a1\u30f3\u30fb\u30d8\u30eb\u30b7\u30f3\u30b0 (\u5b57\u5e55\u7248)'
```

However, this value is only giving me the Japanese **within** the CDATA tag.

How would I get the **entire** value within the title element. That is, `<![CDATA[ ヴァン・ヘルシング (字幕版)]]>`?

Comment: Once it's been parsed by lxml you don't have access to the source, just the DOM nodes.  If you know it's CDATA, why can't you just re-wrap it in `<![[CDATA[ ... ]]>` yourself?  CDATA is a serialization detail.  In your example, the XML would be semantically  identical with or without the CDATA wrapper.

Comment: One reason is because I'm not certain if the element will have a `CDATA` tag. For example, for English titles, there would be no `CDATA` wrapper.

Comment: As I said earlier, CDATA is a serialization detail.  It need not be there unless the data contains characters that would break XML parsing, such as `<`.  The fact that the text is Japanese has nothing to do with CDATA being required or not.

Comment: Got it. However, this is how the xml metadata is -- whether that matters at a technical level or not (I am not writing the specs nor can I alter them).

Comment: Also note that I can do insert the CDATA wrapper an alternate way (by getting the language of the information and based on that value). I was just seeing if there was a way to do it at the db level.

Comment: You shouldn't need to worry about CDATA. It's only really a helper if you're writing XML by hand. As far as the XML infoset is concerned, `ABC` is exactly the same as `<![[CDATA[ABC]]>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to find a solution here in terms of the parsing of the full value. Instead, I am using a `CDATA` wrapper based on some other logic.

Comment: What makes you think you even *need* to preserve CDATA nodes?

Comment: Ask Apple. It is their specs.

Comment: Spec for what? Any application that consumes XML as XML should not care whether a CDATA was used in the serialization of the infoset.